# 2010 Workflow with Designer email plus approval on library column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to create a workflow in designer where it sends the email to the group managing the library that a new request as been added to the library which is working but then I need to send another email to the created:by that the request was either approved or Denied which is determined by a column dropdown in the library and if denied include the reason based on another column text field. What is the best way to create this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same workflow which starts when an item is added to a library and make sure to check the box 'Start workflow automatically when an item is changed'

Create two steps in your workflow and add a condition for the

1st step to check if the workflow status is NOT 'Approved' or 'Denied' - send an email to the group managing the library.

2nd step to check if the workflow status is 'Approved' or 'Denied' - send an email to 'CreatedBy', you can also add currentitem:Reason field in the body of the email.

Comment: How do I check the status as not approved or denied what command allows me to put a or in the step?

Comment: Ok so when I finish the email to notify them that a request has been submitted to the library I wait for edit menu table to start to contain the column that is a dropdown of Approve and Denied. Then I created the two steps. In the first Step I am running in parallel waiting for the status to contain approved or denied then log in the settings. then in the 2nd step I run the If approved do this else denied do this. which just emails the created:by. and in the case of the denied I did look up the column that the host can edit. Should this work?